# Refresh Excel Connection on Office 365 using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, office365, webdav

There is a Office 365 site with several Excel documents which must have their connections refreshed every 6 hours. My hope was to develop a simple PowerShell script to:

1. Checkout and open a file.
2. Refresh connections.
3. Save and checkin file.

I wrote this simple PowerShell script to refresh any paths passed as arguments, and send a success/email notification to the developers. My plan is to use `Task Scheduler` to schedule this to execute periodically, passing the SSL (WebDav) paths of my Excel files.

Example Path:

```
\\microsoft.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\teams\project\files\Workbook.xlsx
```

PowerShell Script:

```
# Configurables
$EmailFrom ="norreply.projectemail@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "myemail@domain.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")


# Open new instance of Excel
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $true

# Give delay to open
Start-Sleep -s 5


Foreach ($file In $args)
{
    Write-Host ""

    $fileName = (Split-Path -Path $file -Leaf)

    If ((Test-Path $file) -And ($excel.Workbooks.CanCheckOut($file)))
    {
        Try
        {
            # The following code applies only for excel files in document library, can be skiped for others
            $excelworkbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
            $excelworkbook = $excel.Workbooks.CheckOut($file)
            $excelworkbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file) # Opening a second time after checkout is required

            # Refresh all data connections.
            Write-Host "Refreshing: ", $file
            $excelworkbook.RefreshAll()

            # Checkin the file
            Start-Sleep -s 15
            $excelworkbook.CheckInWithVersion()

            SendSuccessEmail $fileName
        }
        Catch
        {
            SendErrorEmail $fileName $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        SendErrorEmail $fileName "Unable to locate or checkout file. Please verify file exists and is checked in."
    }
}

# Close Excel instance
$excel.quit()
```

This works well, but only so long as my token remains active. I do this by clicking the "Open with Explorer" button in SharePoint. At this point, I'm able to use my SSL WebDav path to access the files. When the token expires the next day, I must again click the "Open with Explorer" button to renew.

Is there any programmatic way to renew my token so that my script continues working longer than a single day, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: maybe you could use `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client` to download the file from your sharepoint server

Comment: here are links describing the download ( http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.de/2014/02/download-file-from-sharepoint-using.html ) and the upload ( http://blogs.technet.com/b/fromthefield/archive/2014/02/19/office365-script-to-upload-files-to-a-document-library-using-csom.aspx )